# Pass node field value to page.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I'm new to Drupal. I've just started a custom theme in Drupal 8 and created a new field under Content Type. This field value is a custom class for each page. From the documentation I should be able to display the field contents of "field_body_class" with the following, neither of which display.

```
{{content.field_body_class}}

{{page.content.field_body_class}}
```

I've checked to make sure the field was not hidden, which it was not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably a bit confused.

Variables are only available in specific templates. So the value of a field which is attached to an entity (like a content type) is only available in the template for that entity.

To make the body class field value available in a different template you need to

- make a preprocess function for the template.
- fetch the entity that has the field
- expose it to the template.

For you it could look something like this.

```
function theme_name_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   // Define {{ body_class }}  in the template.
  if (!empty($variables['node']) && !empty($variables['node']->field_body_class)) {
    $variables['body_class'] = $variables['node']->field_body_class->value;
  }
}
```

Comment: That helps a bunch, but I am certainly confused. I was using it in the specific page template. `page--node--2.html.twig` Shouldn't it be available?

Comment: @Klav No this is expected behavior

Comment: @NoSssweat You don't get it - he wants to add the value from the body class field to the actual body class, which lives in the page template. So he can't use the node template for anything

Comment: @googletorp thx, I get it now, this is nifty.

Answer (score 0):

The [page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page.html.twig/8.9.x) template doesn't get any `content` variable. It gets a `page.content` variable, but that is the rendered content of the *content* region, which means you won't get `page.content.field_body_class`.

To get the field value, you need to implement a preprocess function for the *node* template and set a new variable initialized to the field value.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node']->field_body_class)) {
    $variables['body_class'] = $variables['node']->get('field_body_class')->value;
  }
}
```